Finding the smallest perfect square whose last 3 digits are the same. How do I do this by hand?

What is the smallest perfect square whose last 3 digits are all the same digit?

After testing different numbers with a calculator, I have found that $38^2=1444$ is the smallest...how would you do so without using a calculator? I've tried writing as
$A \cdot 10^3 + 111 \cdot B = k^2$ and playing around with it, taking mod $3$ and $37$ (since $111=3\cdot37$), but those have yielded nothing...
Also, I know it must be 4 digit since $100^2=10,000$ is also a perfect square with its last 3 digits the same.

Once you know it is 4 digits, then since $\sqrt{1000}$ is about 33 so even if you have to multiply by hand, it won't take you long to find 38.

That is assuming you know that 38 is the answer.

You are trying to find the smallest so it makes sense to start with 33, 34, 35...

Joke answer: $0^2=000$.

Based on Mathematica experiments, I'd conjecture that 38 is in some sense the "only" nontrivial example. Specifically, any other example I've found is either of the form $n=100k$ (so $n^2$ ends in 000) or $n=\pm 38\mod{500}$.

@Semiclassical:  according to my answer, the last three digits are $000$ or $444$, and the solutions to $n^2\equiv444\bmod1000$ are precisely $n\equiv\pm38\bmod500$

Every perfect square must end with an even number of zeros. So, if a perfect square ends in at least $3$ zeros, then in fact it must actually end in at least $4$ zeros.

Incidentally, it looks like it's impossible for a square to end in 4444: if it did, it would be of the form $10000n + 4444 = 4 (2500n + 1111)$, so it would have to be the case that $2500n + 1111 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ which is impossible.

Closely related: Quadratic residues mod 100000

100 squared is 10000, which ends in three repeated digits. This may not be the smallest solution but you need not keep testing beyond 100. This works in any base.

As pointed out by heropup in an answer that has now been deleted, the last digit of a square must be $0, 1, 4, 5, 6, $ or $9.$  But the last two digits of a square must leave remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$, so they can’t be $11$, $55$, $66$, or $99$. That leaves $000$ (which probably doesn’t count), $444$, $1000$, $\color{red}{1444}$…

Assuming that $A = 0$, that is $k^2 = B\cdot111$, we arrive at a contradiction since $B \in \{0, \ldots, 9\}$ (and assuming $k$ is taken to be nonzero).
If $A = 1$, then $k^2 = 1 \mod 37$, so $(k+1)(k-1) = 0 \mod 37$. And because $37$ is prime, $k = \pm 1 \mod 37$. In other words
$$
k = 37x \pm 1,
$$
for some integer $x \in \{1, 2\}$ (as $k \leq 100$). The case $x = 1$ includes the correct value of $k = 38$.

Let us note the 2-digit number $k = 10a + b$ and let's suppose that $k^2 = 100a^2 + 20ab + b^2$ has the last 3 digits being the same.
Then the last two digits must have the same parity, but the $100a^2 + 20ab$ part cannot change the parity of these digits, so actually $b^2$ must have $2$ digits of the same parity !
We can then eliminate $1^2 = 01$, $3^2 = 09$, $4^2 = 16$, $5^2 = 25$, $6^2 = 36$, $7^2 = 49$ and $9^2 = 81$ because the 2 digits have different parity.
This leaves only $b = 0$, $2$ or $8$ as possibilities, thus we have the repeating digit $B = 0$ or $4$.
If we start from $k = 32$ to have $k^2 \gt 1000$, we stumble pretty quick on the correct answer $k=38$.

What about $b=0$?

Ooops good point, adding the case $b =  0$

I like your reasoning (+1), but I think you should replace the last paragraph with more of your reasoning: If $b=0$ then the smallest non-zero solution is $100^2$.  If $b=2$ then the last two digits are $12$ or $62$.  However $12^2=144$ so whatever the remaining digits, the "hundreds" digit will always be odd.  If the last two digits are $62$ then the last three have to be $462$ or $962$, of which  $462^2$ gives us the smallest answer.  This leaves $b=8$.  The last two digits are $38$ or $88$.  However $88^2=7744$, whose third digit is odd, so no solutions will end $88$.  $38^2= 1444$.

So the smallest solution is $38^2$, $100^2$ or $462^2$, of which $38^2$ is clearly the smallest.

In fact you get a complete list of three digit solutions: $38, 538, 462,962, 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900$, which I see has already been enumerated by@J.W.Tanner.
